# Closed form of composition of Möbius transformations

Tags: complex-analysis, closed-form, mobius-transformation

Consider a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers $\{\epsilon_n\}_n$ converging to $0$ and a sequence of complex numbers $\{a_n\}_n$, in modulus strictly increasing and diverging to $\infty$.

Define
$$
g_n(z)=\frac{\epsilon_n}{z-a_n}\;;
$$
$g_n$ is the Möbius transformation corresponding to the matrix
$$G_n=
    \left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & \epsilon_n \\
    1 & a_n \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]\;.
$$
Is there any way to find a closed form for the composition $h_n=g_n\circ g_{n-1}\circ\cdots\circ g_1$ (respectively the product of matrices $H_n=G_nG_{n-1}\cdots G_1$)?

In particular, fixed $R>|a_n|$, I am interested in finding the 2-dim Lebesgue measure of
$$
\{z\in\Bbb C\;:\;|h_n(z)|>R\}\;.
$$

Comment: Since the eigenvalues of $G_n$ are $\frac12(a_n+\sqrt{a_n^2+4\varepsilon_n}) \approx a_n$ and $\frac12(a_n-\sqrt{a_n^2+4\varepsilon_n}) \approx \frac\varepsilon{a_n^2}$, matrix multiplication by $G_n$ is going to be very similar to a projection onto its dominant eigenline together with multiplication by $a_n$. Furthermore, those dominant eigenvectors become very close to $[0 1]$. Thus I would suspect that the product acts very much like multiplication by $a_n\cdots a_n$ on the second coordinate and $0$ on the first coordinate. Hope that vague notion is helpful....

Comment: Thanks Greg, I have to work on it.